# Merge leads to casting error DATETIME --> INT

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-merge

I can't figure out why this error is occurring. Can anyone else help me spot the error?  I'm trying to merge into a temp table, and getting the error

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the 
>    CONVERT function to run this query. The error is identified as occurring on the line where the MERGE starts.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    BookID AS KTSID,
    ResourceID AS FLRID,
    ls.ID AS SiteShelfID,
    ls.CustomerNumber AS SiteCustNum,
    ls.DivisionID AS SiteDivID,
    st.DateCreated AS SiteBibDateAdded,
    st.TotalCopies AS SiteQtyOwned,
    ls.ParentLibraryShelfID AS ProviderShelfID,
    NULL AS ProviderCustNum,
    NULL AS ProviderDivID,
    NULL AS ProviderBibDateAdded,
    NULL AS ProviderQtyOwned
INTO #TitleData
FROM dapadmin.ShelfTitle st
    JOIN dapadmin.LibraryShelf ls ON st.LibraryShelfID = ls.ID
    JOIN #TitlesToInclude tti     ON st.ID = tti.ShelfTitleId


MERGE #TitleData WITH(HOLDLOCK) AS td
    USING (SELECT 
            st.BookID AS KTSID,
            st.ResourceID AS FLRID,         
            st.LibraryShelfID AS SiteShelfID,   
            ls2.CustomerNumber AS SiteCustNum,
            ls2.DivisionID AS SiteDivID,
            s.ProviderShelfID,
            ls.CustomerNumber AS ProviderCustNum,
            ls.DivisionID AS ProviderDivID,
            st.DateCreated AS ProviderBibDateAdded,
            st.TotalCopies AS ProviderQtyOwned
        FROM @ShelfIdsToSearch s
        JOIN dapadmin.ShelfTitle st 
            ON s.ProviderShelfId = st.LibraryShelfID
        JOIN #TitleData td 
            ON td.KTSID = st.BookID 
            AND td.FLRID = st.ResourceID
            AND td.SiteShelfId = s.LibraryShelfId
            AND td.ProviderShelfID = st.LibraryShelfID      
        JOIN #TitlesToInclude tti 
            ON st.ID = tti.ShelfTitleId
            OR s.ProviderHasChanged = 1
        JOIN dapadmin.LibraryShelf ls
            ON s.ProviderShelfId = ls.ID
        JOIN dapadmin.LibraryShelf ls2
            ON s.LibraryShelfId = ls.ID
        ) AS pt

    ON td.KTSID = pt.KTSID 
        AND td.FLRID = pt.FLRID
        AND pt.SiteShelfID = td.SiteShelfID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
        SET ProviderCustNum      = pt.ProviderCustNum,
            ProviderDivID        = pt.ProviderDivID,
            ProviderBibDateAdded = pt.ProviderBibDateAdded,
            ProviderQtyOwned     = pt.ProviderQtyOwned
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (KTSID, FLRID, SiteShelfID, SiteCustNum, SiteDivID, 
            SiteBibDateAdded, SiteQtyOwned, ProviderShelfID, 
            ProviderCustNum, ProviderDivID, 
            ProviderBibDateAdded, ProviderQtyOwned)
    VALUES (pt.KTSID, pt.FLRID, pt.SiteShelfID, pt.SiteCustNum, pt.SiteDivID, 
            NULL, NULL, pt.ProviderShelfID, 
            pt.ProviderCustNum, pt.ProviderDivID, 
            pt.ProviderBibDateAdded, pt.ProviderQtyOwned)
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a guess that `ProviderBibDateAdded` is typed as integer and you are tying to stuff a datetime into it,  Try changing your update statement to this:

```
UPDATE
    SET ProviderCustNum      = pt.ProviderCustNum,
        ProviderDivID        = pt.ProviderDivID,
        ProviderBibDateAdded = Cast(pt.ProviderBibDateAdded as Integer),
        ProviderQtyOwned     = pt.ProviderQtyOwned
```

and your insert statement to this:

```
INSERT (KTSID, FLRID, SiteShelfID, SiteCustNum, SiteDivID, 
        SiteBibDateAdded, SiteQtyOwned, ProviderShelfID, 
        ProviderCustNum, ProviderDivID, ProviderBibDateAdded, 
        ProviderQtyOwned)
VALUES (pt.KTSID, pt.FLRID, pt.SiteShelfID, pt.SiteCustNum, 
        pt.SiteDivID, NULL, NULL, pt.ProviderShelfID, 
        pt.ProviderCustNum, pt.ProviderDivID, 
        cast(pt.ProviderBibDateAdded as Integer), 
        pt.ProviderQtyOwned)
```

If this is indeed the issue, then you might instead create your temp table with explicit data types to start off with, before you insert anything into it.

```
Declare @TitleData (
     KTSID integer not null,
     FLRID integer not null,
     SiteShelfID integer not null,
     SiteCustNum varChar(??),
     SiteDivID integer not null,
     SiteBibDateAdded Datetime not null,
     SiteQtyOwned smallInt,
     ProviderShelfID integer not null,
     ProviderCustNum varChar(??) Null,
     ProviderDivID Integer null,
     ProviderBibDateAdded Datetime null,
     ProviderQtyOwned null)

Insert @TitleData (KTSID, FLRID, SiteShelfID, 
    SiteCustNum, SiteDivID, SiteBibDateAdded,
    SiteQtyOwned, ProviderShelfID)
SELECT BookID, ResourceID, ls.ID,
   ls.CustomerNumber, ls.DivisionID,
   st.DateCreated, st.TotalCopies,
   ls.ParentLibraryShelfID
From dapadmin.ShelfTitle st
    JOIN dapadmin.LibraryShelf ls 
       ON st.LibraryShelfID = ls.ID
    JOIN #TitlesToInclude tti     
       ON st.ID = tti.ShelfTitleId
```

Comment: But ProviderBibDateAdded is a DATETIME, not an integer.  I see now that when I created the first table, I passed in a NULL for ProviderBibDateAdded, so I'm guessing the default type is INT. Is there a way to specify DATETIME as the type of a column in a temp table that's created by SELECT...INTO? Or do I need to explicitly CREATE the table to do that?

Comment: Also, the suggested change doesn't make the error go away....  BUT, if I apply a cast in the UPDATE clause as well, then the error DOES go away. So your guidance about the source of the problem is correct. Thanks for the rapid response!

Comment: it was just a guess, based on supposition that `ProviderBibDateAdded` is typed as integer and you are tying to stuff a datetime into it. If `ProviderBibDateAdded` is a datetime, then this is dead end, sorry.  Something else is trying to stuff a datetime into a field or memory variable that is expecting an integer.  But that is the only place I see in your code that might have been the errant assignment.

Comment: I think you must have commented before seeing my edit to the second comment. You are correct about the ProviderBibDateAdded being the problem. So now my question becomes, in creating the original table, can I say something like "NULL AS DATETIME", so that I can later stick DATETIME values into that column.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what to do.  But why not create the temp table, (or table variable, with explicit data typoes to start off with?  See my edit t see...o

Comment: Yup, I'll change over to defining the temp table explicitly, so I can specify the data type for that column. Thanks again!